# How do you configure the java heap size for zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to set up Zookeeper 3.4.10 on an Ubuntu 18.04LTS Azure VM.

Per the [ZooKeeper Administrator's Guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.10/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance)
"incorrect Java heap size
You should take special care to set your Java max heap size correctly. In particular, you should not create a situation in which ZooKeeper swaps to disk..."

The guide does not give instructions on how to set the max heap size. I've already done a little searching and found suggestions to create a java.env in the zookeeper/conf directory. I've done this and have tried setting the variable using two different methods I've found during research:

Attempt #1:

```
export JVMFLAGS="-Xmx6144m"
```

Attempt #2

```
#!/bin/bash
export CLASSPATH="~/zookeeper-3.4.10/conf/log4j.properties"
export JVMFLAGS="-Xmx6144m"
```

After making these changes, and restarting zookeeper, I checked the java heap size with:

```
java -XshowSettings:vm
```

And the max heap size is not changing.

What are the proper steps for configuring the max heap for zookeeper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary release of Zookeeper contains `bin` directory with following files in which you interested in:

- zkServer.sh
- zkEnv.sh

`zkEnv.sh` defines location of all config files and some JVM tuning knobs, such as JVM heap size. JVM heap size can be changed by shell variable `ZK_SERVER_HEAP`(in MB).
Use following command to set custom heap size:

```
cd bin/
ZK_SERVER_HEAP=128 ./zkServer.sh start-foreground
```

In output of recent versions of Zookeeper you can find following lines:

```
2021-01-14 17:24:18,400 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@98] - Server environment:os.memory.free=114MB
2021-01-14 17:24:18,400 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@98] - Server environment:os.memory.max=128MB
2021-01-14 17:24:18,400 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@98] - Server environment:os.memory.total=128MB
```

Other JVM opts can be set using `SERVER_JVMFLAGS`, for instance, use non default GC:

```
ZK_SERVER_HEAP=128 SERVER_JVMFLAGS="-XX:+UseShenandoahGC" ./zkServer.sh start-foreground
```